# Loop over array values and produce a different ouput of column names

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I need your help.

I was wondering as to whether or not it would be possible to modify a for loop, that loops over array values and outputs column names based on the array values but to also only have (1) occurrence of a single item thus producing a different column name. Here is a picture of what the javascript code outputs to date:

[image]

Here is the desired output. As you can see, its more visually appealing to the eye without the use of repetition. As I will be tallying numbers later under the column names.

[image]

Here is the Javascript code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function search_array(arr, str){
  var searchExp = new RegExp(str,"gi");
  return (searchExp.test(arr))?true:false;
}

function build_sheet() {

    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")

    var Book = Excel.Workbooks.Add()

    var Sheet = Book.ActiveSheet

    var temp = "BNI to President","BNI to Director","BNI to Manager","BNA to President","BNA to Director","BNA to Manager"

    var c = 2 /* Start position @ Column 2*/

    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

        if (search_array(temp[i], "BNI to") == true) {
            Sheet.Cells(2,c).Value = "Briefing Notes (Info)"
        }
        if (search_array(temp[i], "BNA to") == true) {
            Sheet.Cells(2,c).Value = "Briefing Notes (Approval)"
        }
        else {
            Sheet.Cells(2,c).Value = temp[i]
        }
        ++c
    }

    Excel.visible = true

    Excel.quit()

    Excel = null

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will 100% work, since I don't have excel and I don't know how you're able to use JS on an Excel spreadsheet, but I'll explain my train of thought first.

If you keep track of any values you've entered into the spreadsheet in a separate array, defined outside of the for loop, then you can check that array to see if `temp[i]` has already been inserted. If it hasn't, then run the rest of your code, which seems to work fine.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function search_array(arr, str){
            var searchExp = new RegExp(str,"gi");
            return (searchExp.test(arr))?true:false;
          }

          function build_sheet() {
            var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")
            var Book = Excel.Workbooks.Add()
            var Sheet = Book.ActiveSheet
            var temp = ["BNI to President","BNI to Director","BNI to Manager","BNA to President","BNA to Director","BNA to Manager"];
            var c = 2 /* Start position @ Column 2*/
            var arr = []

            for( var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
              if (arr.indexOf(temp[i]) == -1) {
                arr.push(temp[i]);
                if (search_array(temp[i], "BNI to") == true) {
                  Sheet.Cells(2,c).Value = "Briefing Notes (Info)"
                }
                if (search_array(temp[i], "BNA to") == true) {
                  Sheet.Cells(2,c).Value = "Briefing Notes (Approval)"
                }
                else {
                  Sheet.Cells(2,c).Value = temp[i]
                }
              }
              ++c
            }
          Excel.visible = true
          Excel.quit()
          Excel = null
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but a simple one is to simply keep track of what was written and if it already was, don't write it again:

```
function build_sheet() {

    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var Book = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
    var Sheet = Book.ActiveSheet;
    var temp = "BNI to President","BNI to Director","BNI to Manager","BNA to President","BNA to Director","BNA to Manager";
    var c = 2; /* Start position @ Column 2*/

    var written = ['info'=>false, 'approval'=>false];

    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

        if (!written['info'] && search_array(temp[i], "BNI to") == true) {
            Sheet.Cells(2,c).Value = "Briefing Notes (Info)";
            written['info'] = true;
            ++c;
        }
        if (!written['approval'] && search_array(temp[i], "BNA to") == true) {
            Sheet.Cells(2,c).Value = "Briefing Notes (Approval)";
            written['approval'] = true;
            ++c;
        }
        else {
            Sheet.Cells(2,c).Value = temp[i];
            ++c;
        }
    }

    Excel.visible = true;
    Excel.quit();
    Excel = null;
}
```

Comment: `++c` will be conditional i believe